# Default value of variables in PHP?

Tags: php

I did a search for this, but I could not find an answer to my question.

When a variable is declared without a value, like this:

```
$var;
public $aVar;
```

Is the value of the variable unknown, as in many languages (i.e. whatever was in memory before), or is the variable by default set to `null`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Variables that are declared without a value and undefined/undeclared variables are `null` by default.

However, just doing `$var;` will not declare a variable so you can only declare a variable without a value in an object.

Demo:

```
<?php
class Test { public $var; }
$var;
$t = new Test();
var_dump($var);
var_dump($t->var);
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: var in - on line 5
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: Note that the `isset()` function returns `FALSE` if the value of the variable is `null`. So, one could say that a variable does not exist in PHP before it receives a value.

Comment: True, one of the bigger PHP WTFs imho.

Comment: @ThiefMaster why would you say its a WTF? The docs clearly say that the isset function "Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.". By default, $var is null, so isset correctly returns false. It's not a WTF.