# Are class variables always NULL before they are initialized?

Tags: php

My class contains some setter methods that set the class variables only if the setter argument is correct. Now I would like to evaluate several of these class variables in one calculation method. How do I make sure that each of these variables already contains a correct value? Is it enough if I check the respective class variable against NULL to see whether a value is set, or can I only access the Getter method within the calculation method, which then checks whether a valid value is included?

To put it briefly: If I define a class variable with 'protected $foo;', is it NULL by default in every PHP version until another value is set, or can an unset variable like in C also contain a random value?

```
class Foo {
   protected $a;
   protected $b;

   public setA($val) {
        $valFiltered = filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if($valFiltered !== false) {
            $this->a = $valFiltered;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
   }

   public setB($val) {
        $valFiltered = filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if($valFiltered !== false) {
            $this->b = $valFiltered;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
   }

   public function sum() {
       if($this->a !== NULL && $this->b !== NULL)
           return $this->a + $this->b;
       else
           return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: `can an unset variable like in C` What's `C`?

Comment: And the default value for any variable or property is NULL until it is set

Comment: Yes it is
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460744/default-value-of-variables-in-php

Comment: Variables in PHP by default is equal to NULL, you can unset variables with `unset` function. `protected $a;` is equal to `protected $a = null;`

Comment: @Neodan: As soon as you unset a class variable it will throw a notice message, so it's not the same state as before. And isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL. So how is it possible to test if a class variable exists when it contains NULL?

Comment: @root66 Don't use `isset()` to test whether class properties are defined, use [property_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker: Perfect, thanks!